# UPDATE command not working mysql.connector

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-python, mysql-connector-python

Im using this website: https://remotemysql.com/ for a sql database,
when I try to update value using sql console on phpmyadmin it works:

```
UPDATE users SET id='someid' WHERE username='myusername';
```

but with python mysql connector it doesnt:

```
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="remotemysql.com",
  user="blahblah",
  password="blahblah",
  database="blahblah",
)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("UPDATE users SET id='someid' WHERE username='myusername';")
mydb.close()
```

the command is executed and doesnt throw an error, but in phpmyadmin theres no visible change, other commands like reading the data work.
Im asking how to make it work?

Comment: Maybe no row matches your `where` clause. Does `select * from users where username = 'myusername'` gives you some results?

Comment: Do not use values insertion, use parameters. See [MySQL Connector/Python Developer Guide  /  ...  /  MySQLCursor.execute() Method](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible reasons.

1. You should use `mycursor.commit()` after your statement, since it's a DML statement.
2. No rows match your `where` clause.

Comment: as I said, this command works on phpmyadmin, I'll try the first case